Need help calculating the total length of a line path in a pdf
i'm trying to create a small application for a friend that has a workshop. I started this as a small project to also advance my java knowledge a bit.
Right now i have some calculations that i made after researching.
The problem is that the calculation does not output the correct number and i'm unsure how to proceed further or where i could find more information to finetune the calculation.
Im using Apache PDFBox
And the pdf i have is checking for magenta colored lines
So my question is the following, can anyone give me more information or some help in getting this calculation right? Right now my pdf should return : 3017,789mm but its length of magenta paths: 7371.512237553014
I dont want to display it or anything, i just need the information
here's my code so far :
public class PdfCalculatorUtil extends PDFGraphicsStreamEngine {
    private double totalLength = 0;
    private Point2D.Double currentPoint = new Point2D.Double();
    private Point2D.Double startPoint = new Point2D.Double();
    private boolean inMagentaPath = false;

    public PdfCalculatorUtil(PDPage page) {
        super(page);
    }

    @Override
    public void appendRectangle(Point2D p0, Point2D p1, Point2D p2, Point2D p3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void drawImage(PDImage pdImage) {
    }

    @Override
    public void clip(int windingRule) {
    }

    @Override
    public void moveTo(float x, float y) {
        currentPoint.setLocation(x, y);
        startPoint.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void lineTo(float x, float y) {
        totalLength += currentPoint.distance(x, y);
        currentPoint.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void curveTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3) {
        // Calculate the length of the Bézier curve segment
        totalLength += bezierLength(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
        currentPoint.setLocation(x3, y3); // Update the current point
    }

    @Override
    public Point2D getCurrentPoint() {
        return currentPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void closePath() {
        totalLength += currentPoint.distance(startPoint);
        currentPoint.setLocation(startPoint);
    }

    @Override
    public void endPath() {
    }

    @Override
    public void strokePath() {
    }

    @Override
    public void fillPath(int windingRule) {
    }

    @Override
    public void fillAndStrokePath(int windingRule) {
    }

    @Override
    public void shadingFill(COSName shadingName) {
    }

    public double getTotalLength() {
        return totalLength;
    }

    public void extractPathLengths(PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            processPage(page);
        }
    }

    private PDRectangle getPageDimensions(PDPage page) {
        return page.getMediaBox();
    }

    private double getUnitsPerPoint(PDPage page) {
        PDRectangle mediaBox = getPageDimensions(page);
        // Calculate the length of the diagonal of the media box
        double diagonalLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mediaBox.getWidth(), 2) + Math.pow(mediaBox.getHeight(), 2));
        // Get the diagonal length in points
        return diagonalLength / Math.sqrt(2);
    }

    private String getPageUnits(PDPage page) {
        double unitsPerPoint = getUnitsPerPoint(page);
        // Determine the units
        if (unitsPerPoint >= 25.4) {
            return "millimeters";
        } else if (unitsPerPoint >= 2.54) {
            return "centimeters";
        } else {
            return "points";
        }
    }

    public void checkPdfUnits(PDDocument document) {
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            String units = getPageUnits(page);
            System.out.println("Page Units: " + units);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) {
        String operation = operator.getName();
        if ("m".equals(operation)) {
            if (inMagentaPath) {
                float x = ((COSNumber) operands.get(0)).floatValue();
                float y = ((COSNumber) operands.get(1)).floatValue();
                moveTo(x, y);
                System.out.println("Move to (magenta): (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            }
        } else if ("l".equals(operation)) {
            if (inMagentaPath) {
                float x = ((COSNumber) operands.get(0)).floatValue();
                float y = ((COSNumber) operands.get(1)).floatValue();
                lineTo(x, y);
                System.out.println("Line To (magenta): (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            }
        } else if ("h".equals(operation)) {
            closePath();
        } else if ("c".equals(operation)) {
            if (inMagentaPath) {
            float x1 = ((COSNumber) operands.get(0)).floatValue();
            float y1 = ((COSNumber) operands.get(1)).floatValue();
            float x2 = ((COSNumber) operands.get(2)).floatValue();
            float y2 = ((COSNumber) operands.get(3)).floatValue();
            float x3 = ((COSNumber) operands.get(4)).floatValue();
            float y3 = ((COSNumber) operands.get(5)).floatValue();
            double segmentLength = bezierLength(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
            curveTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
            System.out.println("Bezier Segment Length (magenta): " + segmentLength);
            }
        } else if ("K".equals(operation)) {
            // Set CMYK color
            float c = ((COSNumber) operands.get(0)).floatValue();
            float m = ((COSNumber) operands.get(1)).floatValue();
            float y = ((COSNumber) operands.get(2)).floatValue();
            float k = ((COSNumber) operands.get(3)).floatValue();
            // Check for magenta color
            inMagentaPath = c == 0.0 && m == 1.0 && y == 0.0 && k == 0.0;
        }
    }

    private double bezierLength(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3) {
        double ax = 3 * x1 + 3 * x2 - x3;
        double ay = 3 * y1 + 3 * y2 - y3;
        double bx = 3 * x1 - 3 * x2 + 3 * x3;
        double by = 3 * y1 - 3 * y2 + 3 * y3;
        double cx = 3 * x2 - 3 * x3;
        double cy = 3 * y2 - 3 * y3;
        double integral = 0;
        int nt = 100; // Increase the number of intervals for better accuracy
        double dt = 1.0 / nt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
            double t2 = Math.pow(i * dt, 2);
            double t3 = Math.pow(i * dt, 3);
            double sqrtTerm = Math.sqrt(ax * t2 + bx * t3 + cx);
            double sqrtTermY = Math.sqrt(ay * t2 + by * t3 + cy);
            if (!Double.isNaN(sqrtTerm) && !Double.isInfinite(sqrtTerm) &&
                    !Double.isNaN(sqrtTermY) && !Double.isInfinite(sqrtTermY)) {
                integral += Math.sqrt(sqrtTerm * sqrtTerm + sqrtTermY * sqrtTermY) * dt;
            }
        }
        return integral;
    }
}



"Right now my pdf should return : 3017,789mm but its length of magenta paths: 7371.512237553014" - what makes you sure it should be the former? Can you share the PDF in question for analysis?

Thanks for your reply. I measured the path in an autocad program. Here's a wetransfer link to the pdf : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2f7ce98cba24461f28e9f065f8f0828e20240429193859/be0e6e

Ok, with the actual test file at my side I looked through your code.
At first glance I saw the following issues

You override processOperator incompletely. If you override it, you have to process all operators of interest. In general the better approach is registering operator classes and letting the PDFGraphicsStreamEngine do its job with the original processOperator code.
For your example file you don't process all of the operators used for path construction in it, you forgot the v and y operators.
For the general case you additionally ignore the current transformation matrix which may be changed by cm and Q calls. Also you ignore the re operator.

Your bezierLength method cannot be correct because it only uses the coordinates of the two control points and the end point but completely ignores the start point.

Your getPageUnits and getUnitsPerPoint don't make sense to me at all. For normal PDFs getUnitsPerPoint will always return a value in the hundredths or even thousands, so your getPageUnits will always return "millimeters" for them. But those files hardly ever have millimeters as units.


